# mongodb change streams java

Tags: mongodb, stream, blocking, watch

Since this feature is relatively new (mongo 3.6) I found very few java examples.
My questions:
1. What is the best practices for watching change streams?
2. Does it have to be a blocking call to watch the stream? (This means a thread per collection which is less desired)
This is the example I encountered:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/change-streams/

The blocking call is:
collection.watch().forEach(printBlock);

Thanks,
Rotem.

Comment: Could you elaborate your questions ? 1) other than the example provided in the manual, what kind of best practices are you looking for ? if you could include some design decision or question that would be good. 2) Why is a single thread per collection less desirable ? what are you trying to do for example ?

Answer (score 1):

Change streams make a lot more sense when you look at them in the context of [reactive streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-reactive-streams). It took me a while to realize this concept has a much broader existence than just the MongoDB driver.

I recommend reviewing the article above and then looking at the example provided [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=mongodb/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams-master/examples/documentation/src/ChangeStreamSamples.java#). The two links helped clear things up, and provided insight on how to write code leveraging the reactive  streams Mongo driver, which is non-blocking.

Answer (score -1):

Use mongo reactive driver so that it will be non-blocking. And we used this approach and running in production for last one month, no issue.